# Can not seem to figure out how to set a token in my request header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, token, access-token, mean-stack

I am following a book tutorial, I am currently building the authentication for the app. Whenever I login correctly, I can't seem to set the token back into the request. The error I am getting is:

```
Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'function () {
        return $window.localStorage.getItem('token');
    }' is not a valid HTTP header field value.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

authService.js

```js
angular.module('authService', [])

// ===================================================
// auth factory to login and get information
// inject $http for communicating with the API
// inject $q to return promise objects
// inject AuthToken to manage tokens
// ===================================================

.factory('Auth', function($http, $q, AuthToken) {
 // create auth factory obj
 var authFactory = {};
 // login user
 authFactory.login = function(username, password) {
  // return promise obj and its data
  return $http.post('/api/authenticate', {
   username: username,
   password: password
  })
  .success(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   AuthToken.setToken(data.token);
   return data;
  });
 };
 
 // logout user by clearing token
 authFactory.logout = function() {
  AuthToken.setToken();
 };
 
 // check if user is logged in
 // checks for local token
 authFactory.isLoggedIn = function() {
  if (AuthToken.getToken())
   return true;
  else
   return false;
 };
 
 // get logged in user
 authFactory.getUser = function() {
  if (AuthToken.getToken())
   return $http.get('/api/me', { cache : true});
  else
   return $q.reject({ message : 'User has no token.'});
 };
 
 
 
 return authFactory;
})
// ===================================================
// factory for handling tokens
// inject $window to store token client-side
// 
// 
// ===================================================
.factory('AuthToken', function($window) {
 var authTokenFactory = {};
 
 // get token out of local storage
 authTokenFactory.getToken = function() {
  return $window.localStorage.getItem('token');
 };
 // function to set token or clear token
  // if a token is passed, set the token
  // if there is no token, clear it from local storage
  
  authTokenFactory.setToken = function(token) {
   if (token)
    $window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  else
   $window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
  };
 
 return authTokenFactory;
})
// ===================================================
// application configuration to integrate token into requests
// ===================================================
.factory('AuthInterceptor', function($q, $location, AuthToken) {
 var interceptorFactory = {};
 
 // this will happen on all http requests
 interceptorFactory.request = function(config) {
  // grab token
  var token = AuthToken.getToken;
  // if token exists add it to the header as x-access-token
  if (token)
   config.headers['x-access-token'] = token;
   
   return config;
 };
 
 // happens on response errors
 interceptorFactory.responseError = function(response) {
  // if 403 from server
  if (response.status == 403) {
   AuthToken.setToken();
   $location.path('/login')
  }
  //return the errors from server as promise
  return $q.reject(response);
 };
 
 return interceptorFactory;
});
```

app.js

```js
var app = angular.module('userApp', [ 
 'ngAnimate', 'app.routes', 'authService', 'mainCtrl', 'userCtrl', 'userService']);
// app config to integrate token into req
app.config(function($httpProvider) {
 // attach our auth interceptor to the http reqs
 $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
});

app.controller('mainController', function($http) {
 // Bind this to view / vm-view model
 var vm = this;
 
 // define variables and objects on this
 // this lets them be available to our views
 // define a basic variable
 vm.message = 'Hey! Message';
 
 $http.get('/api/users')
 .then(function(data) {
  // bind users to vm.users
  vm.users = data.users;
 }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In custom interceptor factory

```
 interceptorFactory.request = function(config) {
            // grab token
            var token = AuthToken.getToken;
            // if token exists add it to the header as x-access-token
            if (token)
                config.headers['x-access-token'] = token;

                return config;
        };
```

change `AuthToken.getToken;` to `AuthToken.getToken();`

and your error was quite clear that you were passing function into header instead of value

```
Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'function () {
        return $window.localStorage.getItem('token');
    }' is not a valid HTTP header field value.
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still unclear why this worked. Im pretty new to js and angular, so forgive me for my lack of expertise.

Comment: so when you do AuthToken.getToken it returns an instance of method its not actually calling the method .